# How do I insert an ICollection Of data into my database .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a model returning this JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "externalIds": {
                "samsara.serial": "G2PV5GN98C",
                "samsara.vin": "2C4RC1AG5KR587515"
            },
            "gateway": {
                "serial": "1111-11N-98C",
                "model": "V1111A"
            },
            "harshAccelerationSettingType": "automatic",
            "id": "28111111111197",
            "licensePlate": "Fake 18",
            "make": "CHRYSLER",
            "model": "Pacifica",
            "name": "Fake 18",
            "notes": "",
            "serial": "G2P111198C",
            "vin": "2C1111111115",
            "year": "2019",
            "vehicleRegulationMode": "regulated",
            "createdAtTime": "2021-10-13T17:10:56Z",
            "updatedAtTime": "2021-10-13T17:10:56Z"
        },
        {
    "data": [
        {
            "externalIds": {
                "samsara.serial": "G2PV5GN98C",
                "samsara.vin": "2C4RC1AG5KR587515"
            },
            "gateway": {
                "serial": "1111-11N-98C",
                "model": "V1111A"
            },
            "harshAccelerationSettingType": "automatic",
            "id": "28111111111197",
            "licensePlate": "Fake 18",
            "make": "CHRYSLER",
            "model": "Pacifica",
            "name": "Fake 18",
            "notes": "",
            "serial": "G2P111198C",
            "vin": "2C1111111115",
            "year": "2019",
            "vehicleRegulationMode": "regulated",
            "createdAtTime": "2021-10-13T17:10:56Z",
            "updatedAtTime": "2021-10-13T17:10:56Z"
        },
    ]
}
```

I have a Database model set like this:

```
    public class SamsaraGpsVehicle
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Vin { get; set; }
        public string Serial { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public string HarshAccelerationSettingType { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have my Context setup like so (Not showing the whole file but its the basic DbContext setup):

```
public class SamsaraContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SamsaraGpsVehicle> SamsaraGpsVehicles { get; set; }

            modelBuilder.Entity<SamsaraGpsVehicle>(e =>
            {
                e.ToTable("samsara_vehicle");

                e.Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("id").IsRequired();
                e.Property(a => a.Name).HasColumnName("name").IsRequired();
                e.Property(a => a.LicensePlate).HasColumnName("tag");
                e.Property(a => a.Make).HasColumnName("make");
                e.Property(a => a.Model).HasColumnName("model");
                e.Property(a => a.Year).HasColumnName("year");
                e.Property(a => a.Vin).HasColumnName("vin");
                e.Property(a => a.Serial).HasColumnName("serial");

                e.HasKey(a => a.Id);
            });
}
```

And lastly I have a controller that fetches this data from an api and returns an ICollection into this model:

```
    public class SamsaraGpsVehicleInfo
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("externalIds")]
        public ExternalIds ExternalIds { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("gateway")]
        public Gateway Gateway { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("harshAccelerationSettingType")]
        public string HarshAccelerationSettingType { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("licensePlate")]
        public string LicensePlate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("make")]
        public string Make { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("serial")]
        public string Serial { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("vin")]
        public string Vin { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("year")]
        public string Year { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("vehicleRegulationMode")]
        public string VehicleRegulationMode { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("createdAtTime")]
        public DateTime CreatedAtTime { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("updatedAtTime")]
        public DateTime UpdatedAtTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExternalIds
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("samsara.serial")]
        public string SamsaraSerial { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("samsara.vin")]
        public string SamsaraVin { get; set; }
    }

    public class Gateway
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("serial")]
        public string Serial { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }

    public class SamsaraGpsVehicleList
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("data")]
        public ICollection<SamsaraGpsVehicleInfo> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

**WHERE I NEED HELP** is iterating or somehow going through the ICollection and turning the response that I am getting and saving it into the  entity database.

Comment: The first step is to map the `ICollection<SamsaraGpsVehicleInfo>` to a collection of `SamsaraGpsVehicle` (your database model).

Comment: Ok this may be a dumb question but How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Enumerable.Select Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0) to convert the `ICollection<SamsaraGpsVehicleInfo>` that you fetch from API to a `List<SamsaraGpsVehicle>`. Then use [`DbSet.AddRange(IEnumerable) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to insert the list to database. This is an example of how your code could look like, you might have to change things according to your existing code:

```cs
using System.Linq;

...

public class MyController
{
    private readonly SamsaraContext _context;

    public MyController(SamsaraContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> InsertVehicles()
    {
        // add your code that fetches the vehicle list from api
        SamsaraGpsVehicleList apiResult = await FetchDataFromApi();

        List<SamsaraGpsVehicle> vehicles = apiResult.Data
            .Select(x => new SamsaraGpsVehicle
            {
                HarshAccelerationSettingType = x.HarshAccelerationSettingType,
                Id = x.Id,
                LicensePlate = x.LicensePlate,
                Make = x.Make,
                Model = x.Model,
                Name = x.Name,
                Notes = x.Notes,
                Serial = x.Serial,
                Vin = x.Vin,
                Year = x.Year,
                Status = null // not sure how Status should be populated
            })
           .ToList();

        _context.SamsaraGpsVehicles.AddRange(vehicles);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```